# Can't get string value from custom dialog in my fragment

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments

I have my fragment where user can send points to another user now I need to create custom dialog where user need to reenter his pin. I done it following few tutorials but value is always null;

```
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
    View confirmation=inflater.inflate(R.layout.confirmation,null);
    pin  = (EditText) confirmation.findViewById(R.id.PinChecker);

    }


    SendPointsButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());

            builder.setView(R.layout.confirmation);

            builder.setPositiveButton("DA", new    DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    pinCheck= String.valueOf(pin.getText().toString());
                    Log.d("Pin",pinCheck);
}
```

I want to assing value from pin(EditText) to string called pinCheck;

Comment: Are you getting any error? please share logcat

Comment: No It's working but pinCheck is always null ^^

Comment: Try pinCheck= pin.getText().toString();

Comment: Try to change like this pin  = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.PinChecker);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should pass the inflated layout (confirmation) to builder.setView() as below:

```
  final View confirmation=inflater.inflate(R.layout.confirmation,null);
  pin  = (EditText) confirmation.findViewById(R.id.PinChecker);

....


SendPointsButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());

        builder.setView(confirmation);

        builder.setPositiveButton("DA", new    DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                pinCheck= String.valueOf(pin.getText().toString());
                Log.d("Pin",pinCheck);
}
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: I have another problem now :/
                                                              java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.

Comment: Well I think this link might help http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-custom-dialog-example/

Answer (score 1):

USe this idea...

```
 builder.setPositiveButton("DA", new    DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
....................

        Dialog D = (Dialog) dialog;
                                    //This is the input I can't get text from
                                    EditText inputTemp = (EditText) D.findViewById(R.id.input_text);

    pinCheck= String.valueOf(inputTemp.getText().toString());

........
}
```

I hope you will get it..

Answer (score 0):

Try accessing the element using the `Dialog` element instead of the `View`, **Like**

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
AlertDialog dialog =builder.create();
dialog.setContentView(confirmation);
..........
dialog.show();
```

And access your `pin` with

```
pin  = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.PinChecker);
```